# What circular saw blade would i use to cut laminate flooring planks?

Tags: flooring, laminate

Can you tell me what circular saw blade and with how many teeth I will need to use for cutting laminate flooring planks?

Answer (score 2):

You will want a fine tooth blade.  The more teeth the better.  This will reduce the risk of chipping the laminate surface.

Comment: Okay so a circular saw blade with more than 60 teeth will work fine for cutting the laminate flooring planks?

Comment: And carbide. Laminate often has aluminum dioxide in its surface coating, which is hard on standard steel blades. Carbide teeth remain sharp longer.

Answer (score 0):

If the laminate is actually wood, then you will want something with as many teeth as possible (a "fine" toothed saw).  You might also want to use masking tape or painter's tape to reduce chipping.  Just tape where you will cut, make your mark, cut with the tape in place, and edge chipping/splintering will be greatly reduced.

If the laminate is vinyl, rubber, or some other similar (softer) material, you may want to use a utility knife (what some people refer to as box cutters), as the softer material may not leave a sharp, clean edge if you use a circular saw (or other saw).